# "Translating" C program to Python3 produces unexpected results

Tags: c, python-3.x, algorithm, syntax

I have some experience in c but I am fairly new to python, so I was trying to "port" one of my programs from c to python to get some practice, but although in my eyes the algorithm I am using should work just fine, the one in python produces wrong results. What am I missing?
Here's the code in C:

```
  int i1=0,j1=0;
  int counter=0;
  bool flag=true;
  z=0;
  for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j<m; j++) {
      i1=i;
      j1=j;
      z++;
      while (i1>=0 && i1<n && j1>=0 && j1<m && flag==true) {
        switch(a[i1][j1]) {
          case 'D':
            if (b[i1][j1]==z) { 
              flag=false;
              break;
            }
            b[i1][j1]=z;
            i1++;
            j1=j1;
            break;
          case 'U':
            if (b[i1][j1]==z) {
              flag=false;
              break;
            }
            b[i1][j1]=z;
            i1--;
            j1=j1;
            break;
          case 'L':
            if (b[i1][j1]==z) { 
              flag=false;
              break;
            }
            b[i1][j1]=z;
            i1=i1;
            j1--;
            break;
          case 'R': 
            if (b[i1][j1]==z) { 
              flag=false;
              break;
            }
            b[i1][j1]=z;
            i1=i1;
            j1++;
            break;
        }
      }
      if (flag==false) {
        counter++;
      }
      flag=true;
    }
  }
```

And here's the code in Python 3:

```
i1=0
j1=0
counter=0
flag=True
z=0    
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(m):
        i1=i
        j1=j
        z+=1
        while (i1>=0 and i1<n and j1>=0 and j1<m and flag==True):
            if (a[i1][j1]=='D'):
                if(b[i1][j1]==z):
                    flag=False
                    break
                elif (b[i1][j1]!=z):
                    b[i1][j1]=z
                    i1+=1
                    j1=j1
                    break
            if (a[i1][j1]=='U'):
                if(b[i1][j1]==z):
                    flag=False
                    break
                elif (b[i1][j1]!=z):
                    b[i1][j1]=z
                    i1-=1
                    j1=j1
                    break
            if (a[i1][j1]=='L'):
                if(b[i1][j1]==z):
                    flag=False
                    break
                elif (b[i1][j1]!=z):
                    b[i1][j1]=z
                    i1=i1
                    j1-=1
                    break
            if (a[i1][j1]=='R'):
                if(b[i1][j1]==z):
                    flag=False
                    break
                elif (b[i1][j1]!=z):
                    b[i1][j1]=z
                    i1=i1
                    j1+=1
                    break     
        if(flag==False):
            counter+=1
        flag=True
```

I haven't included the complete code, but this is the problematic part. Please assume that the arrays are properly declared and initialized in both cases.
Any Help Appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1):

In your C code, `break;`s are used for exiting from the `switch` statement.

On the other hand, `break`s in your Python code mean to exit from the `while` statement.

You should remove all the `break`s not to unexpectedly get out of the loop.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I just assumed that there wouldn't be any difference between the two "breaks" so I didn't bother to do any research. Works perfectly fine now.